# How to Create AWS Aurora MySQL Serverless v1 Database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am having troubles creating a AWS Aurora MySQL Serverless v1 Database. I want to stick to v1 instead of v2 mainly because of the 0 ACU option and the Data API feature.

Here are the engine options:

[image]

In the info section, it says Serverless v1 is available on version 5.7.2. However, I tried selecting all these engine options one by one, but none of them displayed the Serverless v1 option in the Instance configuration.

Also, here in this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.Aurora_Fea_Regions_DB-eng.Feature.ServerlessV1.html), it says Aurora MySQL v2.08.3 supports Serverless v1 for my region, but it is not in the engine options list. I cannot even create it from AWS CLI 2, using "aws rds create-db-instance" function, since it says "Cannot find version 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.08.3 for aurora-mysql"

Am I doing something wrong?

Just to compare with the PostgreSQL, in the info section it says versions 11.18 and 13.9 support Serverless v1. And it actually displays the option when I select these engine versions.

In this case do I have to stick with PostgreSQL? Would it be a good idea if I clone one of my existing Serverless v1 DB clusters? Is there any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why the version Aurora MySQL 5.7 2.08.3, which supports Serverless V1 does not show in the engine options.

But I have managed to create it using AWS CLI 2 using the following command:

```
aws rds create-db-cluster 
    --db-cluster-identifier "<my-db-cluster-name>" 
    --engine "aurora-mysql" 
    --engine-version "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.08.3" 
    --engine-mode "serverless" 
    --scaling-configuration MinCapacity=1,MaxCapacity=1,SecondsUntilAutoPause=1000,AutoPause=true 
    --master-username "<my-username>" 
    --master-user-password "<my-password>"
```

More info here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.create.html